# combining split with findall

Tags: python, split, python-re

I'm splitting a string with some separator, but want the *separator matches as well*:

```py
import re

s = "oren;moish30.4.200/-/v6.99.5/barbi"
print(re.split("\d+\.\d+\.\d+", s))
print(re.findall("\d+\.\d+\.\d+", s))
```

I can't find an easy way to combine the 2 lists I get:

```
['oren;moish', '/-/v', '/barbi']
['30.4.200', '6.99.5']
```

Into the desired output:

```
['oren;moish', '30.4.200', '/-/v', '6.99.5', '/barbi']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `re.split` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in *pattern*, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

So just wrap your regex in a capturing group:

```
print(re.split(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)", s))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Q2cjAp/1)):

```py
s = "oren;moish30.4.200/-/v6.99.5/barbi"

x = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+|.+?(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+|\Z)", s)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
['oren;moish', '30.4.200', '/-/v', '6.99.5', '/barbi']
```

Comment: Oh wow, I think this is better than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re
s = "oren;moish30.4.200/-/v6.99.5/barbi"
print([x for y in re.findall(r"(?:([A-Za-z;\/-]+)|(\d+\.\d+\.\d+))", s) for x in y if x])
```

Result:

```
['oren;moish', '30.4.200', '/-/v', '6.99.5', '/barbi']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use re.findall and a pattern to match:

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+|\D+(?:\d(?!\d*\.\d+\.\d)\D*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\d+\.\d+\.\d+` Match 3 times 1+ digits with a single dot in between
- `|` Or
- `\D+` Match 1+ chars other than a digit
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\d(?!\d*\.\d+\.\d)` Match a single digit asserting not the digits and dots pattern to the right
  - `\D*` Match optional chars other than a digit
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJIvNI/1).

EXample

```
import re

s = "oren;moish30.4.200/-/v6.99.5/barbi"
pattern = r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+|\D+(?:\d(?!\d*\.\d+\.\d)\D*)*"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['oren;moish', '30.4.200', '/-/v', '6.99.5', '/barbi']
```